# How to filter values from showing up in a Looker Studio Time Series Chart

Tags: charts, time-series, filtering, looker-studio

I have a table from Google Sheets with the following structure:

| timestamp | answer |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2024 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 01/01/2024 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 01/02/2024 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 01/02/2024 00:00:00 | 2 |

Now I use a `time series chart` to display the data as following (it basically averages the entries above per week):

[image: time series in google lookerstudio]

I have a list of entries for a few days per week. I aggregate them into the time series chart per week. So if a week does not have any entries, therefore the average is 0.

I know there is the possibility to filter entries within the chart definition. But I don't want to filter any values from the source. I would rather like to filter certain values from showing up in the chart. For example, I don't want to show the data around december 18, 2023.

How can I achieve that?